# Vertx event bus interceptor blocking the request call

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am trying to send data over event bus when got the call from client and response back to client.

Everything is working fine until  i add the interceptor on event bus..

Here is the Code:-

```
public class TestVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> promise) {

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        vertx.exceptionHandler(globalExceptionHandler -> {
            System.out.println("Exception not handled in application  : " + globalExceptionHandler.getCause());
        });

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("test", handler -> {
            System.out.println("Message receive form event bus : " + handler.body().toString());
            handler.reply(handler.body().toString());
        });

        router.get().handler(this::rootHandler);
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080, resultHandler -> {
            if (resultHandler.succeeded()) {
                promise.complete();
            } else {
                promise.fail(resultHandler.cause());
            }
        });

        vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(handler -> {
            System.out.println("Outbound data : "+handler.body().toString());
        });

//        vertx.eventBus().addInboundInterceptor(handler -> {
//            System.out.println("Inbound data : " + handler.body().toString());
//        });
    }

    private void rootHandler(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        JsonObject msg = new JsonObject().put("path", routingContext.request().path());
        vertx.eventBus().request("test","Hello from Application",reply -> this.replyHandler(routingContext,reply));
    }

    private void replyHandler(RoutingContext ctx, AsyncResult<Message<Object>> reply) {
        HttpServerResponse response = ctx.response()
                .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("Reply from event bus : " +reply.result().body().toString());
        if (reply.succeeded()) {
            response.setStatusCode(200)
                    .setStatusMessage("OK")
                    .end(reply.result().body().toString());
        } else {
            response.setStatusCode(500)
                    .setStatusMessage("Server Error")
                    .end(new JsonObject().put("error", reply.cause().getLocalizedMessage()).encodePrettily());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new TestVerticle(), deploymenHandler -> {
            if (deploymenHandler.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("verticle deplyed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Promise<Void> promise) {
        System.out.println("Exiting verticle");
        promise.complete()
    }
}
```

One more doubt is when I stop the application from IDE the Stop method is not called, but If I undeploy this verticle from another verticle that is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using eventbus interceptors you will have to call the `next()` method in the handler otherwise you will get stuck there.

```
vertx.eventBus().addOutboundInterceptor(handler -> {
  System.out.println("Outbound data : "+handler.body().toString());
  handler.next();
});

vertx.eventBus().addInboundInterceptor(handler -> {
  System.out.println("Inbound data : "+handler.body().toString());
  handler.next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help me on second Issue where stop method is not called, and how can I make the data secure over event bus so it should not be visible

Comment: Please describe it further how do you run/stop your program. About security i would recommend opening a new question, maybe someone else has more insight about it.

Comment: Like If I stop from editor or if press ctrl+c on console to stop the running application

Comment: I see now, you are just using a main method and deploy it there. The problem is that when you close your program the ide just kills the java process. You are supposed to use the vertx launcher: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vert_x_launcher . There are tutorials on the topic eg.: https://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/